# SwiftUI Focusable View with Tab/Keypress for iOS

Tags: ios, focus, swiftui

Considering there are bluetooth keyboards for iPhones/iPads and iPad keyboards, is there a way to make a view, button, Text, NavigationLink focusable on tab?

I tried to use the view modifier "focusable," but could not get it to work on iOS.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button/3264261-focusable

Thank you for the help.